# Get value from the object array and modify it's content before using it

Tags: php, joomla, multidimensional-array

Sorry i don't know under which keywords i should find the answer, but here is the problem:

There is a `$data->cart_show;`, while doing `var_dump()` on it, i get this values:

```
string '<a style ="float:right;" href="/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;view=cart&amp;Itemid=105&amp;lang=en">Cart content</a>' (length=124)
```

I need to remove `style` attribute and add a custom `class` on it, (i need to do it in a view file and not in a controller or model) so it becomes like this:

```
<a href="#SameURL" class="customClass">Cart content</a>
```

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like this must be done in model, controllers or in view helpers. Such logic shouldn't be in a view itself. But what you want could be done in two ways:

1) Use a `regular expression` and replace your 'style' attribute by a 'class' with [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function

2) Use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to modify your existing element

Comment: thanks, i will try that. btw why i want to do it in a view file, is that iam using joomla, and i can't override the model or the component file while templating the website. So it's the only way to without corehack